# How to mix voice audio

Tags: c++, audio, voip, signals

I am currently developing a simple VoIP project where multiple clients send out his voice to a server and later the server will mix up those voices together.

However, I can't mix it directly by using simple mathematic addition. Each cycle, a client will send 3584 Bytes voice data to the mixer.

Below is the snippet of the value contained in a receiver buffer:

```
BYTE buffer[3584];

    [0] 0        unsigned char
    [1] 192 'À'  unsigned char
    [2] 176 '°'  unsigned char
    [3] 61 '='   unsigned char
    [4] 0        unsigned char
    [5] 80 'P'   unsigned char
    [6] 172 '¬'  unsigned char
    [7] 61 '='   unsigned char
    [8] 0        unsigned char
    [9] 144 ''    unsigned char
    [10]    183 '·' unsigned char
    [11]    61 '='  unsigned char
     .
     .
     .
```

I'm not so sure how the pattern inside the buffer is generated in that way from a client side but I'm thinking it may be a wave pattern. Now let say I have another similar data like this, how do I mix the voice together.

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: have you tried dividing the result of simple mathematic addition by the number of input buffers (arithmetic mean)?

Comment: @smerlin I've tried but what I can hear is just a silence. Any other method to try?

Comment: @Chicko Bueno: it should work for uncompressed PCM-Data, could be that your audio data is compressed as pointed out by John Zwinck.

Comment: @smerlin as far as I know, a client supplies uncompressed PCM data. This gives me headache.

Comment: @smerlin anyway, could you please provide me a simple mathematic formula if I have 3 clients? Maybe I did a wrong way.

Comment: @Chicken Bueno `serversample[i] = ( client[0].sample[i] + client[1].sample[i] + client[2].sample[i] ) / 3` (samples are not necessary bytes, but could be e.g. 16 bit integral values or floats, so you have to convert the bytes to sample format first, before doing arithmetic).

Comment: We also need more information on the stack being used (the format of the audio being one factor of that). Though I highly doubt it, we don't know if the VoIP stuff is checksum'ing the samples it receives and rejecting any modifications that were made.

Comment: @smerlin is right. You have to be aware of the sample format though as doing that math directly on the bytes won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your data again and they appear to be floating point values the reason I was mistaken in my previous post is probably related to me working on big endian systems for a while now. However your data is in little endian IEEE floating point. Here are the values I got after conversion.

```
0.089630127 -> 0x0090b73d
0.084136963 -> 0x0050ac3d
0.086303711 -> 0x00c0b03d
```

As you can see, the values are fairly small so you'll probably need to take that into account when applying the volume; the usual convention is to have this data either between 0..1 or -1..1 for min and max volumes respectively.

Here is part of a mixing loop I've written a few years ago, for reference the full mixer is [available here](http://code.google.com/p/krryn/source/browse/trunk/audio_mixer.cpp)

```
   for(int i = 0; i < a_Sample->count() / a_Sample->channels(); i++){
            float l_Volume = a_Sample->volume() * m_MasterVolume;

            *l_Output++ += *l_Left * l_PanLeft * l_Volume;
            *l_Output++ += *l_Right * l_PanRight * l_Volume;

            l_Left  += a_Sample->channels();
            l_Right += a_Sample->channels();
    }
```

Notice that for the output you'll probably need to convert the data to signed integers so communicate properly if that's the responsibility of the mixer or the outputting device.

Answer (score 3):

You need to find out if your VoIP system uses compression.  It probably does, in which case the first thing you need to do is to decompress the streams, then mix them, then recompress.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably an array of floats (unlikely due to the byte pattern presented) or singed integers if it's raw PCM data so try using it as such. Mixing to PCM streams is fairly trivial, just add them together and divide them by two (use other weighting for volume control).

Comment: Divide-by-two avoids overflow (if you use a larger type as a temp - typically 32-bits), but is also makes each voice 3db lower.  In a mixer, you generally don't want to reduce the volume of a voice - but this can lead to overflow, so you may have to implement a good (or even crude) form of limiter (even just saturated-add limiting) or AGC.  Note that if both signals are below the -3db point, they **can't** overflow (at that sample).

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned you have to know what format the buffer is in. You can't simply just operate on the bytes directly (well, you could, but it would become quite complicated). Most raw PCM data is usually 44100 bits/second, 16 bit, 2 channel. However, that's not always the case. Each one of those can be different. It won't effect it too much, but is an example. However, even WAV files can be in other formats (like IEEE Float). You will need to interpret the buffer correct as the appropriate data type in order to operate on it.

Like:

```
BYTE buffer[3584];
if (SampleTypeIsPcm16Bit())
{
    short *data = reinterpret_cast<short *>(buffer);
    // Rock on
}
else if (SampleTypeIsFloat())
{
    float *data = reinterpret_cast<float *>(buffer);
    // Rock on
}
```

Of course, you can make it more generic with templates, but ignore that for know :P.

Keep in mind that if you are dealing with floats, they need to be capped to the range -1.0 and 1.0.

So, are you currently saying the "add two values and divide by two" (mentioned by Jasper) isn't working? How are you playing the data when you just hear silence? I wonder if that's a problem because if your math is off, you would likely hear audio glitches (pops/clicks/etc.) rather than just silence.

Comment: Thanks Jason. Actually, I'm doing the mixing part only. My partner is doing the voice capturing and playback. When I tried out Jasper technique, i was a silence playback. No pops, clicks or orgasm voice :P. Let say if the voice is not in PCM format (raw / binary data), how do I mix them?

Comment: Well, it's hard to say. It all depends on the format of the audio stream you are processing. You really need to know that before mixing them together (as different techniques would have different effects on different types). It's not even entirely clear whether this is all audio data (as it could be a proprietary container containing audio data instead of all audio data).